# Is the Fréchet quotient space given by the induced seminorms?

Tags: quotient-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, frechet-space

We admit the following definition of Fréchet space.

> **The definition of Fréchet space:**
> Let $X$ be a linear space and let $\{p_i:X\to\mathbb R^+\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ be a countable family of seminorms such that
> $p_i(x)\ne 0$ for some $i\in\mathbb N$ whenever $x\ne 0$.
> Then we can equip $X$ with a bounded metric
> $$d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} \frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}.$$
> Such a metric space $(X,d)$ is called a **Fréchet space** if it is complete.

The question is:

> Let $(X,\{p_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N})$ be a Fréchet space,
> and $A$ be a closed linear subspace of $X$.
> We want to show that $X/A$ is still a Fréchet space (in the sense of the above definition).

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space), it says that a quotient of a Fréchet space by a closed subspace is a Fréchet space, so I believe that the answer is true.

**My attempt**

1. First we can show that each seminorm $p$ on $X$ induces a seminorm $\tilde p$ on $X/A$ as follows:

The $\tilde q$ is given by
$$
  \tilde{p}:X/A\to\mathbb R,\quad [x]=x+A\mapsto \inf_{a\in A}p(x+a).
$$
In the next we show that $\tilde q$ is a seminorm.
Fix some $\varepsilon>0$. For $x,y\in X$, we pick $a,b\in A$ such that
$$
 p(x+a)-\varepsilon\le\tilde{p}([x])\quad\text{and}\quad
 p(y+b)-\varepsilon\le\tilde{p}([y]).
$$
Therefore,
$$
  \tilde{p}([x])+\tilde{p}([y])\ge p(x+a)+p(y+b)-2\varepsilon \ge 
  p(x+y+a+b)-2\varepsilon \ge \tilde{p}([x+y])-2\varepsilon.
$$
By the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$, we get the subadditivity of $\tilde{p}$.
Since $A$ is a linear subspace,
$$
  \tilde{p}(c[x])=\inf_{a\in A}p(a+cx)=|c| \inf_{a\in A} p(a+x)=|c| \tilde{p}([x]).
$$
So we get the absolute homogeneity.

2. Therefore, each $p_i$ induces a seminorm $\tilde{p_i}$ on $X/A$.
   Then **we want to show that $(X/A,\{\tilde{p_i}\}_{i\in\mathbb N})$ forms a Fréchet space.**

But **I got stuck on showing that $\tilde p_i([x])\ne 0$ for some $i\in\mathbb N$ whenever $[x]\ne 0$.**
I tried as follows.

Suppose $[x]\in A$ and $[x]\ne 0$. Then $x\in X\setminus A$.
Since $X$ is complete and $A$ is closed, we can pick $a\in A$ with $d(x,a)=d(x,A)$.
Since $x\in X\setminus A$, we know $d(x,a)>0$, i.e.
$$
  \inf_{a\in A} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{p_i(x-a)}{1+p_i(x-a)}>0.
$$
What I need to show is that $\tilde p_i([x])=\inf_{a\in A} p_i(x-a)> 0$ for some $i$. I got stuck on this.

Any hints will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In general, without further hypotheses on the seminorms, it is not true that $\tilde p_i([x])=0$ for every $i$ implies $[x]=0$. For example, take $X=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ the space of all real sequences, $p_i(x):=|x_i|$, and $A=\mathbb R\cdot v$, where $v=(1,1,1,\dots)$. The subspace $A$ is closed, but the $\tilde p_i$ defined on $X/A$ are all identically zero.

To fix the above issue, it is sufficient to consider a family of seminorms on $X$ such that $p_i\leq p_j$ whenever $i<j$. You can always assume this condition in the definition of Fréchet space without loss of generality (if it’s not satisfied, consider the new family of seminorms $(q_i)_i$, with $q_i=\sum_{i=1}^ip_i$…; a space with such a family of seminorms is usually called [graded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#Graded_Fr%C3%A9chet_space)), and it is often useful to consider for technical reasons. If this condition is true, then it is indeed true that the $\tilde p_i$ separate points: if $\tilde p_i([x])=0$ for all $i$, then there exists $a_n\in A$ such that $p_n(x-a_n)\leq 2^{-n}$. Since $p_i\leq p_n$ eventually, $p_i(x-a_n)\to 0$ for any fixed $i$, which implies that $a_n$ converges to $x$, thus $x\in A$ if $A$ is closed.